# PHP Get seconds between two unix times?

Tags: php, time, unix-timestamp

So I have been looking around and I cant seem to calculate the seconds between 2 unix times here are my two values:

1617258294 == start_time
1617258315 == current_time

Im using the following code:

```
 $now = new DateTime();  
 $current_time = $now->getTimestamp();;
        
 $difference1 = $current_time - $start_time;
 $difference = $difference1 / 1000 / 60;
```

And I get this value when calculating the difference: 26954.30525

But I have no clue how to convert that to seconds? Please could someone take a look :)

Comment: Unix time stamps are already in seconds (number of seconds since the epoch: 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970),  so a simple: `time1 - time2` will give you the difference in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamps have to be noted with a starting '@' character when initializing `DateTime` classes.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('@' . $unixTimestamp1);
$date2 = new DateTime('@' . $unixTimestamp2);
```

You can calculate the difference between two `DateTime` objects with the `diff` method.

```
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
echo $interval('%s seconds');
```

An alternative use case for DateTime classes using Unix timestamps is the method `setTimestamp`.

```
$date = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($unixTimestamp);
```

I guess that 's all you have to know for dealing with time comparison, date time objects and unix timestamps.

PS: Yes, unix timestamps are in seconds based on the 01.01.1970. You can also just subtract them.

```
$diffInSeconds = $timestamp1 - $timestamp2;
```

Comment: hey perfect so im doing everything correctly but I'm setting the unix times seconds apart so surely I cant be getting unix times this large how can I convert it to say like "4 seconds apart" etc etc rather than 26954.30525

Comment: What format is `$start_time`? Why do you divide by 1000 and then again by 60? Seems that you 're not doing everything correctly.

Comment: So, when you want the difference in seconds ... why are you dividing by 1000 and again by 60? A unix timestamp represents the seconds since 1970-01-01 until now. When subtracting two unix timestamps the result will be the difference in seconds.